# simultaneously use Google Play Location Service and Android platform location APIs

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, locationlistener

is it possible to simultaneously use Google Play Location Service and Android platform location APIs, to try and acquire the current position.
This will be implemented using two LocationChanged listeners.
the app will use the location that is got first from any of the listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is feasible, but not advised. It will have very bad effect on the performance and will also drain battery a lot as both providers will seek for locations.
Imho you will be better off choosing one over the other and depending on your particular use case you can pick. Comparatively, Google play services' location provider gives more accurate location than platform API.

Here's some useful links that'll help:
1) [This article](https://antoniohongkr.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/google-play-service-analysis-4-choice-between-google-play-location-service-and-android-location-service/) will make the distinction clear.
2) Freshly released [Google Play Services 7.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/).